Bug with Clicking: Typing, Clicking, and Selecting Glitching and Jumping
Is anyone else having a difficult time clicking on buttons (for example, to view questions that I posted, my profile, other people's questions) and typing? I've restarted everything and it seems like Stack Exchange is still the only site on my computer having issues. I'll be typing and the blinking cursor will disappear and the page will jump downward. It does the same thing if I try to press a button. If I open the hamburger menu, it will open for a split second and then disappear before I can click anything. The tags bar is doing the same thing, where it will open a tag for a moment and then disappear before anything can be selected.
I am using Chrome Version 128.0.6613.138 running on Windows 11. JavaScript and Cookies are enabled and Images are not blocked.

For the starter: Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?

Any additional details, maybe even a GIF video of you demonstrating the problem, would be helpful in diagnosing this issue. At the present time, from what you've given, I haven't experienced anything like this.

It's possible this is caused by a browser extension too. Can you confirm the behaviour persists with no extensions? Another thing: could also be something wrong with your keyboard. Pressing space bar will jump you down the page, for example.

A Bluetooth mouse (eg.) is supposed to be immune to interference that might cause this sort of thing - I'm just waiting for the media announcement that this is no longer true.

This did happen to me with a bugged mouse, that for each click registered two clicks. So e.g. the first click opened a menu, then the second click closed it. Try to replace to a different mouse, and likely the problem will be "solved".

It turns out it was my malware protection extension (Malwarebytes Browser Guard). Thanks to Robotnik for that suggestion!
I went through all my extensions, turning them off and testing it out, and that was the one causing the problems with typing and clicking. None of the other extensions (Zotero, etc) seemed to cause any issues. I haven't been using a separate mouse recently, just the touchpad, and when I do, it's a USB plug-in one, so I can't give input on the mouse interaction issues!

Cheers, you can accept your own answer as well. (though it will not give you reputation, just so it's marked accepted)

It might be helpful to know which malware-protection extension it was, in case other users encounter the same issue.
